# Facebook Session is NULL after authentification with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can login with my facebook app but the session I get is alway NULL.
Here is my whole PHP Code:

```
<?php


session_start(); //Session should always be active

  $app_id               = 'mySexyAppID';  //DEV Name: PHP_SDK-Prev-FB\0.0.2b4
  $app_secret       = 'someS3cr3tStuff';
  $required_scope   = 'public_profile, publish_actions,publish_stream,manage_pages,user_groups'; //Permissions required
  $redirect_url         = 'http://localhost/fb/facebook-sdk-v4-sample-files/index2.php'; //FB redirects to this page with a code

  require_once __DIR__ . "/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php"; //include autoload from SDK folder

  //define output vars
  $responseMembers_String  = '0';

  //import required class to the current scope
  use Facebook\FacebookSession;
  use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
  use Facebook\GraphUser;
  use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

  FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id , $app_secret);
  $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);

  /**************************************************************/
  // see if a existing session exists
  if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // create new session from saved access_token
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

    // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
    try {
      if ( !$session->validate() ) {
        $session = null;
      }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
      // catch any exceptions
      $session = null;
    }
  }  

  if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
    // no session exists
    try {
      $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
      $_SESSION["FBSession"] = $session;
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
      print_r( $ex->getMessage());
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
      print_r( $ex->getMessage());
    }

  }

  // see if we have a session
  if ( isset( $session ) ) {
      $_SESSION["SessionSetText"] = "Session set with success!";
  }
  /**************************************************************/



  //if user wants to log out
  if(isset($_GET["log-out"]) && $_GET["log-out"]==1){
      unset($_SESSION["fb_user_details"]);
      //session ver is set, redirect user 
      header("location: ". $redirect_url);
  }

  //Test normal login / logout with session

  if ($session){ //if we have the FB session
      //get user data
      $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
      $user_accounts = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
      $user_groups = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/groups'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

      //save session var as array
      $_SESSION["fb_user_details"] = $user_profile->asArray(); 
      $_SESSION["accounts"] = $user_accounts->asArray();
      $_SESSION["groups"] = $user_groups->asArray();

      $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["id"] ) )? $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["id"] : "";
      $user_name = ( isset( $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["name"] ) )? $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["name"] : "";
      $user_email = ( isset( $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["email"] ) )? $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["email"] : "";

      //session var is set, redirect user 
      header("location: ". $redirect_url);

  }

  if(isset($_POST["group_submit"]))
      {
          //user wants informations about a group where he is administrator
          $userGroupId = $_POST["usergroups"];
          //$group_url = '/'.$userGroupId.'/members';

          //request members via facebook graph api  
          /**************************************************/
          $requestMembers = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$userGroupId.'/members');
          $requestMembers_response = $requestMembers->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

          /**************************************************/

          $responseMembers_String =  $requestMembers_response;
          $_SESSION["GroupMembers"] = $responseMembers_String;
      }
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo StackOverflow</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="index2.php">
          <?php

              if(isset($_SESSION["fb_user_details"]))
              {
                  print 'Hi '.$_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["name"].' you are logged in! [ <a href="?log-out=1">log-out</a> ] ';
              }
              else{
                  //display login url 
                  $login_url = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => $required_scope ) );
                  echo '<a href="'.$login_url.'">Connect with Facebook</a>';
              };
              ?>
          <br />
          <br />
                  <?php
                  if(isset($_SESSION["fb_user_details"]))
                  {
                      print 'Some infos about the current user ['.$_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["first_name"].']: <pre>';
                      print_r($_SESSION["fb_user_details"]);
                      print '</pre>';   
                  };
                  ?>

          <br />
          <select name="usergroups" id="ugroups">
                      <?php 
                          foreach ($_SESSION["groups"]["data"] as $group) {
                              //only fetch groups where user is admin!
                              if($group->administrator)
                              {
                                  echo '<option value="'.$group->id.'">'.$group->name.'</option>';  

                              }
                          } ;
                      ?>
          </select>
          <br />
              <button type="submit" class="button" id="group_submit" name="group_submit">Get some informations!</button><br />
          <label id="GroupMembers" name="GroupMembers"><?php if (!(isset($_SESSION["GroupMembers"]))){print 'not set now!';} elseif(isset($_SESSION["GroupMembers"])) {print 'the selected group has '.$responseMembers_String.' Members';} ?></label><br />
          <label id="lInfos" name="lInfos"><?php if (!(isset($_SESSION["FBSession"]))){print '$session not set!!';} elseif(isset($_SESSION["FBSession"])) {print 'Session set!';} ?></label>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I call a graph function (request members of a group: `$requestMembers = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$userSelectedGroupID.'/members');`) I get the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given
```

I have updated the question and added the full example with all the code. 
I realized, that I have the session anywhere because i can select the groups of the user.

Comment: You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/4.0.0 on how to use it. You need to generate the url and click on that

Comment: I've updated my question with the login code. It is already done like it has to be @WizKid

Comment: Can you update the code to show your final code. Because the two different pieces you posted don't work with each other

Comment: Just to be sure, you've set your domain and site url in the facebook app admin?

Comment: I've set the Site URL to 'http://localhost/fb/facebook-sdk-v4-sample-files/' @Ryan

Comment: You said when you call FacebookRequest() you get an error, but that's not seen in the file anywhere. Can we see the block of code that's called in, or can you var_dump $session right after it's created to see if it exists at that point?

Comment: Code updated again @Ryan

Comment: It's hard to get a grasp of what's really going on, since the code is broke up so much. I understand you don't want to show everything, though. The only thing I can add is that typically a null session is caused by a call to `getLoginUrl()` after the redirect.

Comment: Ok, i will try to build an example with all the neccesary code and update the question asap @Ryan

Comment: @Hack4Life, take a look at this tutorial to help you setup authentication and session correctly: https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/

Comment: @Ryan I have edited the question with a working example (expet the error that i get).

Comment: @NirajShah I have also added the code from your site but I still get no session.. Please take a look at the updated question

Comment: Not sure how this works. The block of code to handle when the form is submitted is below a block of code that checks if `$session` exists, and redirects if it does exist. The only way it would get to the block `if(isset($_POST["group_submit"]))` is if the `$session` wasn't set.