# Facebook $session not set after login [SDK 4.0]

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

The variable $session is not set after the login process on Facebook.
Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('fbconfig.php'); //my config files, where I've defined $appId and $appSecret
session_start();

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/home/.../web/www/fb-sdk/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/fb-sdk/autoload.php';


use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $appSecret);


$redirect_url = 'http://example.com/login.php';
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
?>
```

And here is the login.php, where Facebook redirects me to after the Facebook dialog:

```
<?php
require_once('fbconfig.php');

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/home/.../web/www/fb-sdk/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/fb-sdk/autoload.php';


use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;

session_start();

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $appSecret);




$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://example.com/login.php');
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
if ($session) {
echo 'Session active';
}else{
echo 'Session not set'; //and this is the case
}

?>
```

In the login.php the var $session should be set, but it isn't. I've already read the documentation about the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper for PHP.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper/4.0.0

/edit
I'm getting some kind of "code" in the browsers adress-bar, however FacebookRedirectLoginHelper doesn't seem to handle the code.
[image: adressbar]

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I solved the problem (thanks to [Ryan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367530/facebook-session-is-null-after-authentification-with-php-sdk#comment41402199_26367530)): First I put all the code into one file, the index.php. It's important not to call `$helper->getLoginUrl` before you're doing this: `$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();`. Otherwise the var $session will be set to NULL. This is how I implemented the code:

```
<?php
require_once('fbconfig.php');
session_start();

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/home/.../fb-sdk/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/fb-sdk/autoload.php';


use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $appSecret);


$redirect_url = 'http://example.com/';
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);


$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}catch(FacebookRequestException $ex){
    // When Facebook returns an error
}catch(\Exception $ex){ 
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}

if ($session) {
    echo 'Logged in';
}else{
    echo "not logged in";

    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(array( 'email', 'user_friends' )) . '">Login with Facebook</a><br/>';
}
?>
```

I also highly recommend NOT to use a subdomain on which the Facebook-App runs. I changed the App-domain from app.example.com to example.com/app and it worked for me, can't explain why. Hope this helps.